# JavaScript copy and paste file from clipboard - works from browser but not from desktop

Tags: javascript, copy-paste

**Update**

Update: It appears to depend on where / how the data is copied. Copying a file from Windows explorer results in the problem behaviour described. If I create a screen clipping in the Snipping Tool however and use the copy button in that tool, then file data can be pasted. I'm not sure what the difference is in the way file data is copied to the clipboard but there is obviously something different.

I'll leave the question open in case anyone can explain why and if there is a way to work around the problem.

---

**Update: Minimal, Reproducible Example**

https://codepen.io/appsoftware/pen/WNwWpzW

Copy a file of say a [cat](https://www.google.com/search?q=cat&sxsrf=ALeKk01gWFge2qbBRvjHAD8vMSiiqxxUCw:1601285820685&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkiJrExovsAhW9R0EAHbG5AmYQ_AUoAXoECBwQAw&biw=1920&bih=920) from your browser and paste onto the green area and you'll see binary data logged to the console labelled 'file data'.

Save that same file to your desktop or somewhere else and copy and paste from your desktop, again to the green area and you will see the console log entry for 'items' is empty.

---

**Problem:** When I paste an image onto the DOM that has been copied from the browser, then the `items`  array contains data and I can process the file.

If however I paste an item that has been copied from the desktop (Win 10), then the `items` array (`DataTransferList`) is empty.

**I know this is not an environment issue (e.g. Win 10 restriction) as I can paste data from the desktop for another 3rd party app on both Ubutu and Windows 10.**

Is there a security restriction or something else that I'm unaware of here? I have tested in Chrome and Firefox.

---

I have included the SO snippet below but the console output doesn't work well so use the CodePen example above if you can.

```js
document.onpaste = function(event) {

    console.log('pasting ...', event)

    var formData = new FormData();

    var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;

    console.log('items', items);

      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

      console.log('item', items[i]);

      var item = items[i];

      if (item.kind === 'file') {

        var blob = item.getAsFile();

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(event) {

          console.log('file data:', event.target.result)

          formData.append('files', event.target.result);

          // .. upload the file
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
      }
   }
}
```

```css
body, div {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: green;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Paste anywhere ...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to post the HTML.

Comment: Rather than post HTML, I've extended the code snippet to clarify where the event is captured. As you can see the paste event is captured on the document, so there is no HTML specific to the problem here (as far as I know, maybe there is an HTML attribute that will fix this ...)

Comment: It would be great to have a [mcve]

Comment: OK, this pen demonstrates the issue. Copy an image from say, google image search, and you'll see binary data printed in the console. Paste from your desktop and you wont. https://codepen.io/appsoftware/pen/WNwWpzW

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."_

Comment: @gb2d I can see binary printed. I'm using Chrome for macOS. Both inline image or image file copied from desktop.

Comment: Are you running into a CORS problem?

Comment: @Andreas - this particular snippet runs in Code Pen but doesn't work well in SO snippets - makes a mess of the console output

Comment: @A Haworth - I don't believe this is a CORs problem as the problem is apparent before anything is posted to the server.